How to generate contours in Maperitive (SRTM index is missing. Error downloading SRTM data)
Why does Maperitive always fail to generate contours with this error message?
Error downloading SRTM data (reason: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.)

I'm trying to create a topographical map from OSM data. For this, I'm using Maperitive.
Unfortunately, every time I try to generate contour lines (Tools -> Generate Relief Contours), I see this error in the Commander tab








Mapertive fails to download SRTM data for contours



> generate-contours
   Loading digital elevation model...
   SRTM index is missing, it will be generated...
   Indexing SRTM tiles for the 'Australia' region.
   Error downloading SRTM data (reason: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.)

How can I use Maperitive to generate contour lines?

The reason you're having this issue is two-fold:

Maperitive hasn't been updated in over 6 years (the lastest update was last modified in 2018), and

Maperitive is closed-source software, so nobody can fork it and fix this bug



⚠ WARNING: Maperitive is closed-source software that is no longer maintained.
You will likely encounter bugs, and -- because the original author is hostile to free software -- nobody can update it  You may want to look into using QGIS instead.

That said, you can import SRTM data into Maperitive manually.
What is SRTM?
Have you ever wondered how you can zoom-in almost anywhere in the world and see contour lines? I always thought that this was the result of some herculean effort of surveyors scaling mountains and descending canyons the world-over. But, no -- it's a product of the US Space Shuttle program.
In the year 2000, an international program called SRTM (Shuttle Radar Topography Mission) was launched into space with the Endaevor Space Shuttle. It consisted of a special radar system tethered to the shuttle with a 60 meter mast as it orbited the earth.








This illustration shows the Space Shuttle Endeavour orbiting ~233 kilometers above Earth. The two anternae, one located in the Shuttle bay and the other located on a 60-meter mast, were able to penetrate clouds, obtaining 3-dimentional topographic images of the world's surface (source: NASA)



When the shuttle returned to earth, the majority of our planet's contours were mapped. This data was placed on the public domain. Today, it is the main data source for elevation data in most maps.
Maperitive tries to download this data from NASA, but apparently something changed in the past 6 years with how it's made publicly available, and Mapertivie now always fails to download it. But, worry not, we have a better source than NASA.
While the data from SRTM was a huge boon to cartographers, it did have some gaps. Namely: elevation data was missing in very tall mountains and very low canyons. Subsequent work was done to fill-in these gaps. One particular source that ingested the SRTM data, completed its gaps, and made the results public is Jonathan de Ferranti's viewfinderpanoramas.org.
We will be downloading .hgt files from View Finder Panoramas in order to generate vector contour lines for our topographical map.
Download SRTM data
Let's download the SRTM-derived relief data from viewfinderpanoramas.org

viewfinderpanoramas.org/Coverage%20map%20viewfinderpanoramas_org3.htm









Click to download the tile where you're mapping. We download eastern Ecuador, which is 'SA18.zip'



The data is split into .zip files projected onto a map. Just click on the square of the map that contains the area that you want to map to download the corresponding .zip file.
You might need to download more than one file. The country lines are absent, so we downloaded both SA17.zip and SA18.zip.
Add data to Maperitive
After you download your SRTM .zip files, create a directory inside your main Maperitive/ directory
cd Maperitive
 
# create data dir for contours .hgt files
mkdir -p Cache/Rasters/SRTMV3R3/

Now, extract all of the SRTM .zip. files that you downloaded above, and copy all the .hgt files into the Cache/Rasters/SRTMV3R3/ directory.
Change DEM Source
Open Maperitive, and execute this in it:
set-dem-source SRTMV3R3










Change the directory for the SRTM data
Add the .hgt (SRTM data) files (downloaded from Viewfinder Panoramas)



Generate Contours
You should now be able to generate contours









Tools -> Generate Relief Contours
Generated Contour Lines



Attribution
The contents of this answer was adapted from this article titled Make Vector Topographic Maps (Open Street Map, Maperitive, and Inkscape)
